# Remove inner side of mask layer from raster (equivalent of clip raster by mask for the inner side, instead of outside)

Tags: raster, qgis-3, clip, masking

### Objective:

- Clip raster by a mask but remove area interior to the mask (instead of the default exterior area, when using *clip raster by mask*)

### Details of Attempts:

1. Clipping raster using the outer boundary as a mask is straightforward. I get the following output after the clipping

[image: Clipped raster using outer boundary]

In this case, the parts of the raster outside the boundary is removed, which is desired.

2. Next step for me is to remove the area of the raster, which is the polygon shown in the figure below
   [image: Inner boundary]

- Clip raster by mask cannot do this, it appears, to remove, by default, the area of the raster outside the mask.
- I tried to combine the inner and outer (boundary) masks into a *single mask*. However, the problem is that there are *overlapping points*.
- I tried to use *Fix Geometries*, but it doesn't seem to work. I have no way to prevent overlapping sections from occurring.
- I tried using *Check Validity*, which yields no regions of *valid output*.
- I tried using *Buffer*, from *Vector Geometry*

### Other Related Information:

- The raster is generated after running a TIN interpolation from a csv file containing latitude, longitude, and altitude
- The mask is a polygon; points from a CSV file containing latitude, and longitude, are converted to lines (*points to path*), and subsequently, *lines to polygon* is used, to convert to a polygon

Comment: You want to do the steps outlined here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/185654/97475

Comment: Or without QGIS, try this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157047/erase-shapefile-polygon-area-from-geotiff

Comment: Thank you very much!